# Prevent tkinter from freezeing using time.sleep() metho inside loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

I am using a time.sleep(2) method to slow down for loop in tikinter but it freezes the windows. So one recommendation was to use after method inside loop in tkinter python. How to use this in below loop so that it print number after 2 seconds.

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    after(2)
```

I want to run loop after 2 seconds. using time.sleep(2) freezes the tkinter window.

The output should be after each 2 seconds

```
0
1
2
3
4
```